# How do I specify what computers can connect to my public facing Windows 2008 R2 server?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I lock down my Windows 2008 R2 Server so only certain computers can connect to it? Ideally it would use some sort of certificates. I've done this in Linux, but I don't know where to start with Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should ask your question over at superuser.com?

Comment: yeah maybe serverfault.  this isn't a SO question.